# Can we create instance from jsonObject?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I need your help , my question is can we create a an instance from JsonObject .

For example the flowing code results by error

```
var player_hand =
{
    x: null,
    y: null,
    height: null,
    width: null,
    style: null,
    set: function(x, y, width, height, style)  
    {
        this.x= x;
        this.y= y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height= height;
        this.style= style;

    },
    draw: function() 
    {
        DrawRect.draw(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height , this.style);
    }
};
var DrawRect =
{
    draw: function(x, y, width, height, style)
    {
        gameContext.fillStyle = style;
        gameContext.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
};

var left_hand = new player_hand(); // error.
```

I know that the last line in my code cause error , but can we do something like it.

Comment: `player_hand` is already a Javascript object, not a constructor function.

Comment: @thefourtheye did you copy me?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yup :-) I thought I would look better as a comment. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: There's no JSON in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`player_hand` is already a Javascript object, not a constructor function.

You need to do something like this.

```
function player_hand(...) 
{
    this.x = null;
    // ...
}
```

then

var left_hand = new player_hand();

should just work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var player_hand = function(){
    return {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        height: null,
        width: null,
        style: null,
        set: function(x, y, width, height, style)  
        {
            this.x= x;
            this.y= y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height= height;
            this.style= style;

        },
        draw: function() 
        {
            DrawRect.draw(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height , this.style);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can use `var left_hand = player_hand();`.

Comment: Actually var left_hand = player_hand(); is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, if you are happy to tell the likes of Internet Explorer 8 and below where to go... you can actually use your `player_hand` "definition" as the prototype in the [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method.

*Simplified example:*

```js
var foo = {
    val: null,
    getVal: function(){ 
        return this.val; 
    }
},

bar = Object.create(foo, {
    val: { value: 'foo' }
});

console.log( bar.getVal() ); // 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, when you create an object with new Something(), Something refers to a function.

If you want to create instances inheriting from the object player_hand, you need to declare a function, say Player_hand() (the convention is to start a constructor name with an uppercase letter), and set its prototype to player_hand:

```
function Player_hand() {}
Player_hand.prototype = player_hand;
```

You can now write:

```
var left_hand = new Player_hand();
```